# How should I build a type in C++ that obfuscate a secret private value and counts how many times it is exposed at compile time?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <std::size_t A, std::size_t B>
    struct IsALesserThanB : std::integral_constant < bool,
    A<B> {};

template <typename T, std::size_t MEC, std::size_t EC = 0>
class Secret {
   private:
    T value;

    template <template <typename U, std::size_t, std::size_t>
              class Secret>
    static inline constexpr Secret<T, MEC, EC + 1> ECAddOne(
        const Secret<T, MEC, EC>&& this_secret) {
        return Secret<T, MEC, EC + 1>{
            .value = std::move(this_secret.value),
        };
        ;
    }

    template <template <typename U, std::size_t, std::size_t>
              class ReturnedSecret,
              template <typename U, std::size_t, std::size_t>
              class Secret>
    Secret(const Secret<T, MEC, EC>&& this_secret) {
        value = std::move(this_secret.value);
    }

    template <template <typename U, std::size_t, std::size_t>
              class ReturnedSecret,
              template <typename U, std::size_t, std::size_t>
              class Secret>
    ReturnedSecret<T, MEC, EC + 1>& operator=(
        Secret<T, MEC, EC>&& this_secret) {
        T value_ = std::move(this_secret.value);
        return Secret<T, MEC, EC + 1>{
            .value = value_,
        };
    }

    template <template <typename U, std::size_t, std::size_t>
              class ReturnedSecret,
              template <typename U, std::size_t, std::size_t>
              class Secret>
    ReturnedSecret<T, MEC, EC + 1>& operator=(Secret<T, MEC, EC>& this_secret) =
        delete;

    template <template <typename U, std::size_t, std::size_t>
              class ReturnedSecret,
              template <typename U, std::size_t, std::size_t>
              class Secret>
    Secret(Secret<T, MEC, EC>& this_secret) = delete;

   public:
    Secret(T&& initialValue) : value(std::move(initialValue)) {}

    template <
        typename Closure,
        typename = std::enable_if_t<std::conjunction_v<
            std::is_invocable<Closure, const T&>, IsALesserThanB<EC, MEC>>>>
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr inline std::tuple<
        std::invoke_result_t<Closure, const T&>, Secret<T, MEC, EC + 1>>
    exposeSecret(Closure closure) const noexcept {
        auto new_secret = ECAddOne(std::move(*this));
        return std::make_tuple(closure(new_secret.value), new_secret);
    }
};

int main() {
    Secret<double, 3, 2> secretString{std::move(69.69)};

    auto length =
        Secret<double, 3, 2>::exposeSecret(std::move(secretString), [](const double& s) { return "69"; });

    std::cout << std::get<0>(length) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Above is the full code that I have tried.

Basically, `Secret<T, MEC, EC=0>` is the secret type that wraps around the inner `T`, where it only allows scoped exposure of the secret via the `expose_secret()` method which should do the following:

1. It takes in a closure as a parameter.
2. It passes a `const T&` reference to the closure and get its returned value (if any, can be void, of course).
3. `expose_secret` **MUST** **CONSUME** `Secret<T, MEC, EC>` and returns the 'same' wrapper but with `EC` = `EC + 1`, i.e. it **MUST** return `Secret<T, MEC, EC+1>`.

[Playground](https://godbolt.org/z/xzTz9q5Eb)

Right now, the main problem I'm facing is:

1. Constructor must return the same type, i.e. constructor of `Secret<double, 1, 0>` can only return a value of `Secret<double, 1, 0>` and **NOT** `Secret<double, 1, 1>`.
2. No static member function can do a similar thing because there is no way to 'construct' a value of any type in C++ without going through its constructor.

Comment: the code you posted does not compile https://godbolt.org/z/K5ecz6TbW. Maybe thats what you refer to with "the main problem" but thats not clear from reading the question

Comment: You should search for "stateful meta programming". I found a really great example with well explanation here: https://mc-deltat.github.io/articles/stateful-metaprogramming-cpp20. It works also with older C++ standards if you use SFINAE instead of concepts.